# Dockerized Pi-Hole breaks DNS for the rest of the containers. How to fix it?

Tags: docker

I just installed PiHole on my Pi4. Cool thing. Now I wanted to write a new docker image which contains a git clone from GitHub which ends in:

```
  fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/…/': Could not resolve host: github.com
```

The pihole docker-compose service:

```
  pihole:
    container_name: pihole
    image: pihole/pihole:latest
    ports:
      - "53:53/tcp"
      - "53:53/udp"
      - "67:67/udp"
      - "80:80/tcp"
      - "443:443/tcp"
    dns:
      - 127.0.0.1 # self
      - 10.0.0.1 # fritzbox
      - 8.8.8.8 # google
    environment:
      TZ: 'Europe/Berlin'
      WEBPASSWORD: …
      ServerIP: '10.0.0.2'
      VIRTUAL_HOST: 'pihole'
      REV_SERVER: 'true' # for local name resolutoin
      REV_SERVER_CIDR: '10.0.0.0/24' # lan
      REV_SERVER_TARGET: '10.0.0.1' # router
      REV_SERVER_DOMAIN: 'fritz.box' # local domain
      WEBUIBOXEDLAYOUT: 'traditional'
    # Volumes store your data between container upgrades
    volumes:
      - './etc/pihole/:/etc/pihole/'
      - './etc/dnsmasq.d/:/etc/dnsmasq.d/'
    # Recommended but not required (DHCP needs NET_ADMIN)
    #   https://github.com/pi-hole/docker-pi-hole#note-on-capabilities
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    restart: unless-stopped
```

All docker containers run in the default network (172…), my router is the DHCP server, the pi the DNS server, the router (fritzbox) is configured to return the RPis IP as the local DNS server.

How can I make DNS inside the docker containers work again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is extremely misleading. The real problem is not DNS, but a libseccomp2 issue.

For Raspbian, upgrade `libseccomp` manually on the host system by using:

```
curl http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libs/libseccomp/libseccomp2_2.5.1-1_armhf.deb --output libseccomp2_2.5.1-1_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i libseccomp2_2.5.1-1_armhf.deb
```

Original post is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263284/apt-update-throws-signature-error-in-ubuntu-20-04-container-on-arm).